# Restructure branches in a multiple tream project environment

Tags: tfs, tfvc

We want to restructure our code which is splitted in many team projects.
The idea is to create a new team project and move all branches to this new Repository dedicated to store code (TFVC not Git).
We need to only move source code, workitems are not concerned.

Old Tree structure:

```
-TeamProject1
   -ProductX
      -Dev
      -Main
      -Release 1.0
   -ProductY
      -Dev
      -Main
      -Release 1.0
      -Release 2.0
-TeamProject2
   -ProductZ
      -Dev
      -Main
      -Release 1.0
```

Desired Tree Structure :

```
-NewTeamProjectForCode
   -ProductX
      -Dev
      -Main
      -Release 1.0
   -ProductY
      -Dev
      -Main
      -Release 1.0
      -Release 2.0
   -ProductZ
      -Dev
      -Main
      -Release 1.0
```

How can we achieve this without loosing history and current not merged changeset between branches.

We have tried to move branches between team projects but folder history is lost too. Relation between branches are strange because we cannot perform merges between branch (dev>main or release>main) only the move changeset is present.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to keep all 3 products in a single Team project. I would follow below approach.

1. Create branch from ProductZ-TeamProject2 to Productz-TeamProject1
2. Convert ProductZ into a Folder. You can easily do this by right clicking the branch
   [image]
3. Rename TeamProject1 to NewTeamProjectForCode
4. Delete TeamProject2 TP